# Two penguins canoeing through the desert

Tags: lateral-thinking

Here's a simple riddle I remembered from a long time ago:

> On a trip to the Sahara desert, you spot two penguins canoeing through the sand. You hear the first penguin ask, "Where's your paddle?" to which the second responds, "Sure does!"

How does this make sense?

---

**Attributions:** I couldn't find a specific author of this riddle, since there's so many copies of it all over the internet. Please feel free to edit this if you know who created this riddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observer's interpretation of what they heard was:

> "Where's (where is) your paddle?" however, the second penguin's interpretation was "Wears your paddle" in that the sand, like sandpaper wears down the paddle.  The penguin, based on their interpretation agreed and replied, "Sure does."